# invalid metadata document url

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, acs

MVC 5
relying party application in azure:
https:// 
[namespace].accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
1. Creating a new project in Visual Studio 2013
2. Click Change Authentication
3. Selecting Organizational Accounts
4. Selecting On Premise
5. On-Premises Authority, entering in
https://
[namespace].accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
6. Click OK.

I get error message: invalid metadata document url https://
[namespace].accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml


note: there is a space betweeen https:// and [namespace] because stackoverflow won't let me enter in the full Url for some reason.


Why am I getting this error on Windwos Server 2012, but not in Windows 8?

Comment: There is no question in your post

Comment: reproduced under Windows 7 behind a proxy

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem but basically if you can hit the metadata xml file

```
https:// [namespace].accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
```

in your browser then its a Visual Studio connection issue.

I restarted VS and it did nothing. I shut down all browsers and browser windows and it did nothing. I rebooted and it did nothing. So finally I just spammed the `OK` button and it eventually (within 20 secs) ran.

Comment: As soon as I ran Fiddler to debug what was going on, the request succeeded?!?